# Sync a complete Android folder to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, synchronization

look like it is a simple task but i really have no idea how to do a 2-way sync. Do I need to keep track of a mapping of google drive file id with my local files?

is there any example to do it? the drive sample is just using the file in content provide which is not targeted for file system.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of local files to handle merge conflicts, we currently don't provide an auto 2-way syncer between Android and Drive and I don't think there are any samples. The issue is on our list to support syncing files with Drive on Android. Please, watch out for new libs we release.

Comment: I am also having similar use case for iOS. Is this feature added to drive library? I want to have two way sync between local iOS folder and google drive.

Comment: Any news, Burcu? It seems it got forgotten in that list :/